# How to do a REST webserver with Delphi as a backend for a big web application?

Tags: delphi, rest, delphi-xe

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959851/using-rest-with-delphi) but was somehow not satisfied with the answers.

I also quickly read (as suggested in that question) the last chapter of Marco Cantù 2010 Handbook, from which I quote the following (I think I can quote such a short text):

> I [Marco Cantù] do have a lot of
>   investment in server side web and REST
>   applications written in Delphi, and in
>   the recent years I've started playing
>   with and introducing at conferences a
>   Delphi Web Application REST
>   Framework119 (that is, DWARF), which
>   at this time is still not publicly
>   available... simply because it is too
>   sketchy and unfinished to be
>   published. I've seen other ongoing
>   efforts to clone Rails in Delphi and
>   offer other REST server architectures.
>   I think that if you want to build a
>   very large REST application
>   architecture you should roll out your
>   own technology or use one of these
>   prototypical architectures.

Considering that I own Delphi XE Professional and DataSnap is not in there and I would like to consider to write large applications too according to the above comments it seems DataSnap is not an option.

Is there even a commercial solution for this? I don't want to consider "my own implementation of REST", I would like to create a webserver that uses some of my datamodules where I use the DAC I choose (Devart in this case).

Final note: my goal is to write the backend for a large web application, on the client I would like to use Ext JS 4.0, but I want to do all the client work in javascript, to take full advantage of EXT JS, so basically I need a webserver just for the data and tracking the state, not for serving webpages.

Comment: This link in post is broken (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959851/using-rest-with-delphi)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To create your REST services, try our Open Source [mORMot project](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=689#p689). Now it is a well known and stabilized project, used world wide in production.

You can use any DAC with the current state of the framework by implementing a custom `TSQLRestServerStatic` class (similar to the `TSQLRestServerStaticInMemory` class, but calling your DAC): so you'll benefit for the ORM and the JSON RESTful architecture, together with the high-speed http.sys kernel-mode server.

The *SQLite3* engine is NOT mandatory with our framework, even if it was designed to work better with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please redirect me to where the documentation is? On this page (http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3+Framework) I read the Startup Hints... But where do I look for the docs you mention there (for example: 1. Read the REST concept part of the documentation; ?) Thanks.

Comment: You have more than 500 pages of detailed documentation and architecture in http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=55  See in particular the SAD document, in which I added a lot of general introduction, including why and how it uses REST. There is an index of keywords, including REST, at the beginning of this SAD document.

Comment: What a huge documentation, really impressive. Will put in to my todo list.

Comment: Update: one year later, mORMot is able to work with any DB back-end, just as with the internal SQLite3 engine. With some impressive speed results (e.g. using Oracle array binding): see http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/07/25/Synopse-mORMot-benchmark for instance.

Comment: It's too heavyweight just for implementing a REST server.

Comment: @user30478 Heavy in which sense? In learning curve for the developer perhaps, but not as its resulting executable size or for setup of a mORMot-based solution. A REST/ JSON server, running on Windows and/or Linux (compiled with FPC) is implemented in a few lines of code - see https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/tree/master/SQLite3/Samples/36%20-%20Simple%20REST%20Benchmark or https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/tree/master/SQLite3/Samples/28%20-%20Simple%20RESTful%20ORM%20Server or the other samples

Answer (score 10):

If you will start an application from scratch, I think the mORMot is a good option if Delphi is your only option. If you choose datasnap you'll have to live with the problems of performance and stability.

I wrote an article on my blog talking about performance and stability with DataSnap (and mORMot) in large applications, you can see it on the following link:

[DataSnap analysis based on Speed & Stability tests](http://robertocschneiders.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/datasnap-analysis-based-on-speed-stability-tests/)

Comment: your answer looks like more a comment for the accepted answer, since both refer to the same product!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: He does say it is an article he wrote, I've edited it so it stands a little better that the article and blog are his.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a look at kbmMW, there is a way to implement a basic REST server based on an event driven HTTP server.

Check `news.components4developers.com` news groups, there you will have a lot of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

FireHttp is a high-performance Web server based on Delphi/Object Pascal language. It supports HTTP 1.1, HTTPS (SSL/TLS), WebSocket, GZip, Deflate, IOCP, EPOLL. It adopts multi-process+multi-threading model, has good stability and concurrency performance, and provides SDK source code. Developers can use SDK to quickly build high-performance cross-platform Web applications.

Comment: When do you expect to release the commercial version?